# Telegram bot setChatPermissions method not working

Tags: url, telegram-bot

I tried to set chat permission for the pilot version of my bot using this url:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/setChatPermissions?chat_id=<chat_id>&can_send_messages=0
```

But I must try it almost 20 times until it really works and the 19 other times, nothing happens.
Wondering I always receive this back even when it does not anything:

```json
{"ok":true,"result":true}
```

What is the problem? Is it a telegram side problem or it's from my url?

Comment: You have not provided enough data. Add to your question the content of the request you are sending, or the code that sends this request.

Comment: @Gander I am not using any code. I am directly using the this url and enter it in my browser; but it doesn't work. this request should prohibit sending any messages in the group but doesn't work.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for this tool? Have you read the FAQ, have you contacted Technical Support? Have you looked anywhere before you asked a question here?

Comment: You know, now it occurred to me that maybe this tool needs some time for the configuration to be changed? The response status suggests that the system has accepted your change. You know, some systems have queues where such tasks are thrown, and it takes time for them to take effect. How long did you wait between requests?

Comment: @Gander I read all and contacted them. But they won't answer in a day or two days or two weeks! I waited 1 sec between my requests :). only can_send_messages=0 works can_invite_users=0 didn't work even after 1 hour! It is not about time

Comment: Sorry, I think I judged your question a little too hastily. Unfortunately, I can't help you because I don't know this tool at all. Edit your question, I'll be able to undo the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct to send it as you send.
Please send the permissions as json:

https://api.telegram.org/bot/setChatPermissions?chat_id=<chat_id>&permissions={"can_send_messages":true}

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this as a *POST* request (or serialize the parameter value in *GET* request). Analyzing the source code of the random tool, I found another method containing parameters of complex types, and it looked like this:

```js
api.sendMessage({
  chat_id: <YOUR CHAT ID>,
  text: 'Click on buttons below',
  reply_markup: JSON.stringify({ /* Object with config */ })
})
```

This, and the syntax described in the documentation, suggests that the `permissions` field must be given:

```js
api.setChatPermissions({
  chat_id: <YOUR CHAT ID>,
  permissions: JSON.stringify({
    can_send_messages: false
  })
})
```

I found the sample code in this repository: [telegram-bot-api](https://github.com/mast/telegram-bot-api/blob/master/examples/init-inline-keyboard.js)